# WIndows 7 Installation shows Error Bootmgr not found. Press alt+ctrl+del to restart

Tags: windows-7, formatting, lenovo-laptop, bootmgr

I have a Lenovo laptop, when I turn it on, it gives me a black screen with a message saying `"BOOTMGR is missing press ctrl+alt+del to restart"`.

And I did it for many times but it did not solve the problem, I even tried to Google the problem and the expert advices but everything in vain. When power is ON, I press for the boot option keys like `F2, F10, DEL` and click on repair option.

My boot option is F2 and I have tried tabbing this key for several times and it did not open the boot menu. Even I've tried to open the system recovery menu (F8), but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

On Lenovo Laptops you enter the BIOS with `F1`. With `F12` you can select a boot medium which you want to start. This is true for most models, some may differ but you didn't say which one you own -- so I assume `F1`. I owned 3 Laptops by now and it was always that wy. If you have a blue `ThinkVantage` key, this leads to an options menu which leds you decide wether to enter BIOS or boot from different medium.

To fix your problem: Have you a Windows 7 CD present? If so. Put it in the drive, boot from cd and choose to "repair the computer" (lower right corner before you start the installation). In the just opened windows you choose "command prompt".

Fo fix your MBR type:

```
Bootrec.exe /FixMbr
Bootrec.exe /FixBoot
```

And you should be done. Type `exit` and reboot your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

That means the boot manager is missing or corrupt. The boot manager is installed on the harddisk, and is the part that allows you to select which OS you want to start. In your case there's probably only one OS, which the boot manager starts by default.

You mention you tried pressing F8 to enter the system recovery menu -> that is the boot manager.

The boot manager is installed as part of the OS install. You need to find a tool to reinstall/fix the boot manager, or you need to reinstall Windows - and you need to be aware that your hard disk may be dead/dying.

Comment: @Adbul "Is there any way to enter Bios Menu." - Yes, there is. How to enter the Bios  depends on the installed Bios, which depends on your laptop manufacturer and sometimes the laptop model. For most Lenovo models, to enter the Bios press F1.

Comment: My question was not about general way of entering into bios, I want  to ask "how to enter in bios menu in this suituation ? where it gives me only error as "BOOTMGR is missing press ctrl+alt+del to restart".Even after multiple restarts its shows the same message without even showing me the F2 or F12 options.

Comment: Same answer. The bios runs first. The bootmanager comes only after the bios is done. You have to enter the bios before the bios loads (or attempts to load) the bootmanager. No matter what OS or bootmanager you have installed (or not installed), entering the bios always works the same way.